# Java - override key processing for list

Tags: java, list, input, components

I have a List added to my applet with focus.

In handleEvent I process all key presses.

I perform action on the keys.

When the keys are arrow keys, the list is also jumping all over the place. This is undesirable. The list should only respond to mouse events not key events.

How can I override or remove the default key processing for the List component?

Comment: What type of list commponent are you using? A JList?

Comment: Sorry its a java.awt.List not swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it is a component that supports KeyListener just add a `KeyListener` and `consume()` it so it doesn't reach component. *Added some additional keys.*

```
jl.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                            int key = ke.getKeyCode();
                switch (key){
                             case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                             case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                             case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                             case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                             case KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN:
                             case KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP:
                             case KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT:
                             case KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT:
                    ke.consume();
                                    break;
                 default: 
                    }
        });
```